# Problem with executing Truffle script:'Exchange' i.e. the smart contract (SC) has not been deployed to detected network

Tags: migration, truffle-console

I am following the tutorial provided at:
[Example of Truffle script](https://betterprogramming.pub/what-are-truffle-scripts-and-how-can-we-use-them-88185acd86dd)

But I have added the ganache, compilation and migrate. In migration I am getting the following error:
$ truffle exec ts2.js
Using network 'ganache'.

```
Error: Exchange has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at Object.checkNetworkArtifactMatch (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/utils/index.js:245:1)
    at Function.deployed (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:85:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My truffle 2_deploy_contracts.js is:

```
const Exchange = artifacts.require("Exchange");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(Exchange);
};
```

The Exchange contract and the script is provided in the tutorial, I have named the script as ts2 and is copied below:

```
// Contracts
const Exchange = artifacts.require("Exchange")

// Utils
const ether = (n) => {
  return new web3.utils.BN(
    web3.utils.toWei(n.toString(), 'ether')
  )
}

module.exports = async function(callback) {
  try {
    // Fetch accounts from wallet - these are unlocked
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

    // Fetch the deployed exchange
    const exchange = await Exchange.deployed()
    console.log('Exchange fetched', exchange.address)

    // Set up exchange users
    const user1 = accounts[0]

    // User 1 Deposits Ether
    amount = 2
    await exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: ether(amount) })
    console.log(`Deposited ${amount} Ether from ${user1}`)

    //...
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  callback()
}
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial works for me with this `truffle-config.js` file :

```
module.exports = {

  networks: {
      development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.8.4",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  }
};
```

Make sure to correctly deploy the smart contract using `truffle migrate --reset`.

Then, I was able to successfully ran `truffle exec ts2.js`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I got the following output:    $ truffle exec ts2.js
Using network 'development'.

Exchange fetched 0x498Ffe59f98b40Ebc4593ce169b0B55545d6Fa07
Deposited 2 Ether from 0x794b13e9b81102957CB0F519b9D4c3496B045B67